# Load Hazelcast map on first call to map.get() API

Tags: hazelcast

I would like to load the Hazelcast IMap on first access/ call to the map.get() call from the Hazelcast client.

Will you please suggest me the best way to resolve this issue.

Currently, we are trying to use Map store,but not sure this will work.

Thanks
Harshad

Answer (score 0):

Please see related doc section: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#initializing-map-on-startup

When you define an EAGER loading MapLoader, when you first call hazelcast.getMap(), data will be loaded to the Map. This way you can make sure that you’ll always have data in your Maps.

Please note that this operation is a blocking call so until all data is loaded to IMap, your first access to the IMap will be blocked.